# Are induced dual maps from a dual pair of maps are again dual to each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

> Let $\phi : E \to F$ be a linear mapping with restriction $\phi_1: E_1$
>   $\to F_1.$ Suppose that $\phi^* : F^* \to E^*$ is dual to $\phi$.Then
>   $\phi^*$ can be restricted to the pair $(F_1^\perp, E_1^\perp).$

I have proved that indeed $\phi^*$ can be restricted to the given pair.However, my question is that **is $\phi_1$ dual to the induced map from the $\phi^*$.**

For me, it should be because the necessary and sufficient condition for the maps to be dual map is satisfied by the original maps already.

Comment: Do you mean $\phi^* \colon F^* \to E^*$?

Comment: @user49640, yes, I forget to reverse the places.Thank you for pointing out.